# Как отловить объект на котором расположина мышка в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Имею `viewfinder` в `mainwindow` и хочу отловить мышку, если она будет находится на `viewfinder` с помощью `bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);`

Пытаюсь реализовать следующим способом:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui->viewfinder) 
   {
    qDebug() << "mouse on viewfinder";
    return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

к сожалению ничего не происходит

Comment: Погуглите про setMouseTracking

Comment: @gil9red погуглил, но так и не понял, как отловить на каком объекте находится мышка

Comment: После setMouseTracking(true) у нужного виджета можно ловить событие QMouseMove без нажатия кнопки мышки. В eventFilter ловите событие для своего виджета и проверяйте что тип события QEvent::MouseMove

Comment: @gil9red что-то до меня не все же не доходит, можете привести пример?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746541/qt-mousemove-event-not-being-caught-in-eventfilter